# java how to change the row "name" into letter instead of numbers

Tags: java

I have a 2D array called `board`:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7

3 5 6 7 8 5

3 5 6 7 8 7
```

I want the value at row 2 and col 3 so I do:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int row = keyboard.nextInt()-1; 

int col = keyboard.nextInt()-1;

System.out.println(board[row][col]);
```

I input 2 and 3 which gave me 6, but what I want to do it instead of having row `name` as numbers such as `0, 1, 2...`, I want them to be A, B, C, so it will look like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5  - "name"

A   2 3 4 5 6 7

B   3 5 6 7 8 5

C   3 5 6 7 8 7
```

So instead of entering 2 and 3 for `row` and `col` I will enter B3.
How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the "B3" in a string. For the row, 'B' - 'A' now is the index to your board; for the column index, use '3' - '0'.

Remember characters differ from the digits by only an offset.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. (I'm new to Java) why 'B' - 'A'? what does that mean and what does that do specifically?

Comment: @AmyLi 'B'-'A' has nothing to do with Java. It is how the characters are encoded in computer. Without specially mentioned from the PO, I assume you are using ASCII charset (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), in ASCII, characters are encoded in one byte, and character B sits 1 position off A. Thus 'B' - 'A' = 1.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Map to accomplish that:**

```
Map<String, int[]> matrix = new HashMap<>();
// I assume you have a process to store the input data into the Map

matrix.put("A", new int[]{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
matrix.put("B", new int[]{ 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5 });
matrix.put("C", new int[]{ 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7 });

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String row = keyboard.next();
int col = keyboard.nextInt() - 1;

System.out.println(matrix.get(row)[col]);
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to write a method that changes a 2 char string input into 2 numbers in which you then use to print out the number you want.

ex: "A1"

if the first char = "A", i = 0;

if the second char = "1", j = 1;

hope this helps